# WSO2 IS whitespaces inside password policy

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have set the following password policy `[\sa-zA-Z0-9]{10,30}$` in WSO2 IS in **Identity Provider->Resident->Password Policies->Password Patterns**.

I have added the \s to support the white spaces but I get an error when trying to add a password with a white spaced within it.

```
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: 30003 - Credential is not valid. Credential must be a non null string with following format, ^[\S]{5,30}$
```

I use WSO2 IS 5.9.

Do I have to set any other special characters in the regular expression or to do additional configuration in WSO2 IS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a regex validation at the user-store level too. You can change them by adding the following config to the `deployment.toml` and restart the server.
(Note: If `[user_store]` is already defined in the deployment.toml add these configs under the same tag)

```
[user_store]
password_java_regex="^[\\sa-zA-Z0-9]{10,30}$"
password_java_script_regex="^[\\sa-zA-Z0-9]{10,30}$"
```

Once the server gets restarted you can see the modified values of `PasswordJavaRegEx` (regex for backend validation in userstore level) and `PasswordJavaScriptRegEx` (regex for UI validation) in `<wso2is>/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml` file.